# How to hide the left navigation in sharepoint 2019 (modern page)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

I wanna to hide SharePoint 2019 Left Navigation in Modern Team Site, like the following screen, Any one know how to config?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Going to site settings > Navigation Elements > Uncheck Enable Quick Launch.

[image]

Comment: "Uncheck Enable Quick Launch." -> it's not work , the left navigator box still here

Answer (score 0):

You can always add an custom css file to your site and add display: none to the div you want to hide.